# Alarm manager and Notification not working after a while

Tags: android, service, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have set an alarm manager and when that alarm is fired up, I have defined a notification to be shown in  onReceive of the receiver.

I have defined alarm manager code in on stop of my activity, so that it starts running only after the app closes

here is the code in onStop method

```
public void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
    // alrm manager called in on stop so that timer starts after we finish the app
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis()+NOTIFICATIONTIME,NOTIFICATIONTIME, pendingIntent);
}
```

I have cancelled the previously made alarm in onresume so that I shouldn't hear the notification while I am in the activity

```
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    //this helps to cancel all the previously made alarms so that no notification in between game
    cancelAlarm(getApplicationContext());
}
public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
```

and this is the alarm receiver which fires up the notification

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // When our Alaram time is triggered , this method will be excuted (onReceive)
        // We're invoking a service in this method which shows Notification to the User

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Uri notificationbark = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.notificationbark);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).setContentTitle("Name").setContentText("text").setSound(notificationbark).setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotifyBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

the notification showed for a day maybe but now it doesn't.

Comment: are You sure that inside Your device under energy savings option, Your app is protected?

Comment: well that is new. how to check that.

Comment: although I have not checked you advise but I think that is not the problem 'cause I am getting notification for other things also the problem is not on my device but it exists with other devices also.

Comment: guys please help I have been waiting for answer for days and for hours on SO.

Comment: the energy options You can find inside the settings. Settings-Energy Saving - Detailed - Screen off: execute (can differ from phone to phone). You have to enable Your app there. As soon as the screen goes to sleep, Your app will not be executed anymore if it is not protected. It´s just a possibility...

Comment: thanks dude but I don't think that is a problem. First of all I can't find the energy saving options can you look at the code and find a technical related problem. But still thanks for helping me out.

Comment: and the notification should shown in repeat mode?

Comment: didn't knew that, can you direct me somewhere. thanks opiatefuchs

Comment: I mean, do You want to repeat the notification every X hour, because You set alarm with setRepeating() ?

Comment: yes that is what I did I wanted to repeat it in specific time interval. it went fine (i was getting notified for a while ) but I think after a day it it stopped notifying me.

Comment: so which API do You use? If You use target API19 and above, all alarms will be inexact by setting setRepeating(). Instead, You have to use setExact and make Your alarm repeat programmatically. For example at the time this alarm fires inside BroadcastReceiver, set the next alarm....

Comment: okay thanks for sticking with me, will try it !!!

Comment: It's been asked 5 years ago and yet there is no solid solution to solve this problem. Thanks google...